# I would like to add more than one gallery using the same jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

I have little jquery knowledge and I am wondering what I'm doing wrong. I would like to place multiple galleries on a page, but I don't know how to set the codes to load them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript is just there to "turn on the magic". Put all the html you need on the page, then initialise it with javascript. The easiest way to understand (though not the most efficient) is just to make many copies of the code you have.

fill in the blanks:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(
   function (){
       $("#pikame1").PikaChoose();
       $("#pikame2").PikaChoose();
       $("#pikame3").PikaChoose();
       ...
   });
</script>
```

fill in the blanks:

```
<ul id="pikame1" class ="pikame clearfix">
...
</ul>

<ul id="pikame2" class ="pikame clearfix">
...
</ul>

<ul id="pikame3" class ="pikame clearfix">
...
</ul>

...
```

exactly like this:

```
.pikame{
 margin-left: 80px;
 }
 .pika_main{
 width:420px;
 margin-top: 100px;
 }

 .pikame li{
    margin:5px;
    margin-top:20px;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid #3e3f41;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;}

/**ADVANCED OPTIONS**/
.pikame li img{position:relative;cursor:pointer;}
.pika_main img{border:2px solid #3e3f41;}
.pika_main{position: relative;margin:0 auto;margin-left:60px; margin-top:32px;}
.pikachoose li{float:left;position:relative;overflow:hidden;list-style:none;}
.pika_play{position:absolute;top:7px;z-index:1;}
.pika_play a{position:relative;margin-left:auto;cursor:pointer;}
.pika_play img{border:none !important;}
.pika_caption{width:100%;height:30px;text-align:center;}
.pika_navigation a{font-size: 12px;color:white;text-decoration: none;}
.pika_navigation a:hover{text-decoration: underline;}
.pika_navigation{padding-top:10px;clear:both;text-align:center;}
```

Let me know if there are any issues with this, as I have changed the css a bit so as not to be super-redundant, could interfere with existing styles.

Comment: without a link to the page there isn't much help we can offer

Comment: i think the codes are conflicting? is there any code like noconflict that i can input so that the codes flow independently?

Comment: Again, without a link to the page in question, a http://jsfiddle.net/ example of the full code, or detailed error messages, I'm really not going to be able to guess blindly at what might be happening.

Comment: then there's the pikame gallery jquery: capturedphotography.ca/js/jquery.jspikame and js: capturedphotography.ca/js/pikachoose-min.js

Answer (score 0):

you can set it manually by giving each gallery a unique id

```
  $(document).ready(
  function (){
      $("#pikame1").PikaChoose();
      $("#pikame2").PikaChoose();
      $("#pikame3").PikaChoose();
      ...
  });
```

or you can also give all your gallery a common css name then run an each function to process them all at once.

```
  $(document).ready(function (){
      $('.pikame').each(function(){
           $(this).PikaChoose();
      });
  });
```

the only thing is the css selectors in your css part is pertaining to an element having an specific id. you can also create more css like that with different ul id's or you can also 
change those selectors to select a class not an id

for example from this:

```
 ul#pikame{
   margin-left: 80px;
 }
```

to this:

```
 ul.pikame{
   margin-left: 80px;
 }
```

notice the selector $('#pikame1') and $('.pikame'). the first one reffers to an id and the second one to a css.

Comment: can you show us the complete code of the page including the jquery plug ins scripts

Comment: then there's the pikame gallery jquery: http://www.capturedphotography.ca/js/jquery.jspikame and js: http://www.capturedphotography.ca/js/pikachoose-min.js

Comment: just put all your jquery script under document.ready function. as i see on your link the  $('body').removeClass('noJS'); and all under this ae outside the document.ready function. please study about the basics of jquery for more info.